# Why was "13" written on the wall as the train leaves District 12 in Catching Fire?

Tags: the-hunger-games, the-hunger-games-catching-fire

Why was "13" written on the wall as the train leaves a tunnel from District 12 in Catching Fire?

[image]

This 13 would seem to me to label a tunnel to District 13 but they're on a train leaving this tunnel, so that makes no sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe because it's a **B** and not **13**?

[image]

There is another one which is to the right which you can make out through the fence.

Comment: Oops... Fail Question

Comment: Duh! Nice answer. ;-)

Comment: @CuriousWebDeveloper ... No worries :D